# Rspec 3.0.0 Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I used 
`gem 'rspec-rails', "~> 2.14.2"` and all my tests works. Now i installed 
`gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0.0.beta'` and I get this:

```
henio@henio-Toshiba:~/git/EduWords$ bundle exec rspec
/home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspec/rails (LoadError)
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/henio/git/EduWords/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/henio/git/EduWords/spec/features/languages_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/henio/git/EduWords/spec/features/languages_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `load'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `each'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1051:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.rc1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/henio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Rails 4.0.3 and Ruby 2.1.1p76. I did `bundle install`. What I'm doing in wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using Rails, you should use `rspec-rails` to integrate Rails with RSpec. Change your gem requirement to this:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
```

RSpec 3 [introduces significant changes](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/the-plan-for-rspec-3), so you’ll have to update some specs.

Comment: OK I changed it but now almost all my tests fail. f.e rspec ./spec/routing/tags_routing_spec.rb:14 # TagsController routing tags routes to #edit

Comment: That’s to be expected, since RSpec 3 changes many things. Why are you upgrading?

Comment: If you want help figuring out why your specs are now failing, you should open a new question.

Comment: You’re welcome; if you mark the question as answered, other people will see you don’t need any more advice.